# How to create an S3 object in a bucket with one Fog call?

Tags: ruby, fog

Here is the [Fog walkthrough of creating a file (an S3 object) in a directory (an S3 bucket)](http://fog.io/1.5.0/storage/):

```
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id        => YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  :aws_secret_access_key    => YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})

directory = connection.directories.create(
  :key    => "fog-demo-#{Time.now.to_i}", # globally unique name
  :public => true
)

file = directory.files.create(
  :key    => 'resume.html',
  :body   => File.open("/path/to/my/resume.html"),
  :public => true
)
```

But it looks to me as though this requires 2 API calls:

1. `connection.directories.create`
2. `directory.files.create`

If I already have the directory (an S3 bucket) created, how do I create an file (an S3 object) with only one Fog call?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you know the directory exists you can do

```
dir = connection.directories.new(:key => 'foo')# no request made
dir.files.create(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, if already have a bucket in which you want to store the file, then what you can do it is the following:

```
bucket = connection.directories.get({BUCKET_NAME})
```

and after that, you will be able to call bucket.files.create, to store files on that bucket.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This needs different access permissions though: *ListAllMyBuckets* and *GetBucketLocation* on all buckets.

Comment: @JosuaSchmid Good catch! :)

Comment: This makes an unnecessary extra request.